# using variables in Polymer functions

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a code like this in Polymer object:

```
toggleList: function(){
    this.$.list.toggle();
}
toggleSign: function(){
    this.$.sign.toggle();
}
```

Can I easily implement function `toggle(var element)` to toggle different types of components?

@edit:

here is what I want to accomplish

```
toggle: function(element-id){
    this.$.{{element-id}}.toggle();
}
```

I want to use one function with argument instead of two functions with different names

Comment: I can't see what this question is about. What do you try to accomplish? What have you tried? What doesn't work as expected? Can you please provide more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
toggle: function(id){
    this.$[id].toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Polymer offers `$$` to specify selector for querying dom. You can find more details [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html).

So in your case, you can have something like

```
this.$$("#list").toggle();
```